# Should Promises still be used?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

And if yes - how?

I have the following IONIC 3 code and I dont know why it works how it works

First of all there is a so called "MusicService" which is responsible for loading the music files from the local storage:

```js
private searchList: string[] = ["sdcard/Music", "sdcard/Download"]

public LoadMusicFromFS(): Promise<void>{
    this.foundMusic = []

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.searchList.forEach((dir)=>{
            this.CheckDir(dir, 0)
        })
    })
}

public foundMusic: Music[] = []
private CheckDir(dir: string, level: number): Promise<void>{
    return this.localFileSystem.listDir("file:///", dir).then((arr)=>{
        arr.forEach((elem)=>{

            if(elem.isDirectory){
                if(!(this.ignoreList.indexOf(elem.fullPath.slice(1, -1))>-1)) this.CheckDir(elem.fullPath.substr(1), level+1)
            }else{
                let fileType: string = elem.name.split(".").pop()
                if(this.searchTypes.indexOf(fileType)>-1){
                    console.log(elem.fullPath + " | " +elem.name+ " --> is Dir? "+elem.isDirectory)
                    let addingMusic: Music = new Music()
                    addingMusic.description.title = elem.name.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")
                    addingMusic.media.filePath = elem.fullPath
                    addingMusic.description.album.name="Test"
                    addingMusic.media.length=100



                    this.foundMusic.push(addingMusic)
                }
            }
        })
    }, err => {})
}
```

And there is also a Page where I call the function from the service:

```js
this.platform.ready().then(() =>{
  this.musicService.LoadMusicFromFS().then(()=>{
    // This will never be printed -- why? 
    console.log("Music List successfully loaded")
  })
  // This loads the correct Music, but only because of references
  this.musicCache=this.musicService.foundMusic
})
```

I dont really get it - why isnt the "then" part working in the Page?

Comment: it is never printed probably because promise got rejected, you have to pass for example second callback to catch it when it gets rejected `then(()=>{ console.log("Music List successfully loaded") }, ()=>{ console.log("Music List error) })`

Comment: Even not that, you never resolve/reject your promise

Comment: You have to call the fist argument of your Promise within the Promise, for `.then()` to work. What is the use of a Promise that is not handling an Asynchronous action, anyways?

Comment: @Vardius But it loads the stuff, so there shouldnt be an error or am I worng?

Comment: @PHPglue I dont really know what the use of it is, but the File plugin of IONIC forces me to use it

Comment: @MauriceNino yes it does load it because promise `CheckDir` is executed but promise `LoadMusicFromFS` is never resolved/rejected, check my answer there is no need to creating another promise here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Syntax) this will help you better understand how promises work.

> The executor normally initiates some asynchronous work, and then, once
>   that completes, either calls the resolve function to resolve the
>   promise or else rejects it if an error occurred. If an error is thrown
>   in the executor function, the promise is rejected. The return value of
>   the executor is ignored.

Your console log is never executed because never `resolve/reject` your promise

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.searchList.forEach((dir)=>{
    this.CheckDir(dir, 0)
  })
})
```

You have to call `resolve/reject` for example

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // reject if searchList is empty
  if (this.searchList.length < 1) {
    reject();
  }
  Promise.all(this.searchList.map((dir)=> this.CheckDir(dir, 0))).then(
    () => resolve(),
    () => reject()
  );
})
```

> The [Promise.all(iterable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method returns a single Promise that
>   resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have
>   resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It
>   rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

You could even do that:

```
public LoadMusicFromFS(): Promise<any[]>{
    this.foundMusic = []

    return Promise.all(this.searchList.map((dir)=> this.CheckDir(dir, 0)));
}
```

instead of wrapping it in another promise.

Comment: That's the wrong documentation though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Syntax

Comment: `Promise.resolve(..)` is not the same as `resolve` function in the first parameter of `Promise` constructor. `Promise.resolve(..)`, as you cited,  'returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value.'

Comment: Thanks. Notice that your proposed code *always* rejects the promise, though.

Comment: Now it resolves/rejects when the *first* `CheckDir` has finished, not all of them.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the final snippet *should* be used, avoiding the [wrapping in a `new Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Vardius thanks that worked out well! allthough that the return type of the function is not Promise<void> but Promise<any[]>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to accomplish is to cache your result once the checkDir finishes.

That makes sense, and it's something you can potentially benefit by using `Promise`.

However, in your code:

```
this.musicCache = this.musicService.foundMusic
```

`foundMusic` is an array, so the assignment here merely assigns the reference to that array `this.musicCache` (i.e. shallow copy). I do not see the point of doing this. Maybe you want `this.musicCache` to be a map of some sort that maps the file path to the music object, or something like that?

Also, as per use of `Promise`, you can construct a value and resolve the promise to that value, and then `then(..)` it.